# How do I check whether a ModelContainer is stored inMemory

Tags: swift, swift-data

I want to write something like this:

```
fileprivate var container: ModelContainer? = nil
func sharedModelContainer(inMemory: Bool) -> ModelContainer {
    if let result = container, result.isInMemory == inMemory {
        return result
    }

    let schema = Schema([
         ModelClass1.self ,ModelClass2.self, ModelClass3.self
    ])
    let modelConfiguration = ModelConfiguration(schema: schema, isStoredInMemoryOnly: inMemory)

    do {
        let result = try ModelContainer(for: schema, configurations: [modelConfiguration])
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            result.mainContext.undoManager = UndoManager()
        }
        container = result
        return result
    } catch {
        fatalError("Could not create ModelContainer: \(error)")
    }
}
```

But I haven't yet figured out how to implement

```
extension ModelContainer {
    var isInMemory: Bool {
        ???
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for something like the following:

```swift
extension ModelContainer {
    var isInMemory: Bool {
        return configurations.contains(where: { $0.isStoredInMemoryOnly })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation on ModelConfiguration isn't clear and how they are handled if multiple configurations exists for one model container.

For a basic scenario when there are never more than one configuration object a solution is

```
var isMemoryOnly: Bool {
    modelContainer.configurations.first!.isStoredInMemoryOnly
}
```

Note the forced unwrapping, if no ModelConfiguration is given it seems one will always be created for us.

The question is what happens when we have more than one configuration, I haven't been able to test this is a good way but I guess we then must have a much more advanced function where we need to identify the correct ModelConfiguration for a given PersistentModel type (other filter as well?) to read the property from the right instance.

Comment: Makes sense. Truth be told, I also got confused with the collection of configurations.